# How to set integer pointer to a number, and make it behave as non-pointer integer?

Tags: c, pointers

This is the current code which isn't working. I need j to be a pointer.

```
Substring(const char a[],int x,int y,char b[])
{
    int *j=0;
    for(x;x<=y&&a[x]!='\0';x++)
    { b[*j]=a[x];
         *j++;}
    b[*j] ='\0';
    return (b);

}
```

The following code works well, the only problem is that j is not a pointer.

```
Substring(const char a[],int x,int y,char b[])
    {
        int j=0;
        for(;x<=y&&a[x]!='\0';x++)
        { b[j]=a[x];
             j++;}
        b[j] ='\0';
        return (b);

    }
```

I want the first code to behave like the second, any ideas on how to do this?
The code compiles and executes, but it stops working. Debugging has not helped.
I can't use more than 1 variable - j.

Comment: Why do you need j to be a pointer, in this case?

Comment: `I need it to be a pointer`. You need to rethink your logic.

Comment: I'd just love to hear why you need j to be a pointer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh no

`int *j = 0;` will make `j` a pointer to 0 (or `NULL`).

Approach 1:

```
int jx = 0;
int *j = &jx;
```

Approach 2:

```
    int *j = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *j = 0;
....
 ///don't forget to free(j);
```

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
int real_j = 0;
int * j = &real_j;

// ...

++(*j);
```

This is of course totally pointless.

Comment: With local variables, there is at least the hope that the compiler eliminates the pointer.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yeah, one can hope, but the compiler can never eliminate delusions on part of the author :-(